# How to solve '10,000.00' is not a valid floating point value when even TFormatSetting is set to en-US

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to get a `Double` from `10,000.00`:

```
aProductData.BuyPriceHT := 10000;
BuyPriceHTEdit.Text := FormatFloat('#,###.#0', aProductData.BuyPriceHT, FCurrencyFormat);
aProductData.BuyPriceHT := StrToFloat(BuyPriceHTEdit.Text, FCurrencyFormat); <-- error here
```

where `aProductData.BuyPriceHT` is a `Double`

```
FCurrencyFormat := TFormatSettings.Create('en-US');
```

**Note**: To the good guys that are going to advice using `Decimals` or `Int64` types to store Currency in db.
I already did it is just that it still buggs me why it does not work.

Comment: From the documentation of `StrToFloat`: "Thousand separators and currency symbols are not allowed in the string."

Comment: It fails because of the comma. Remove it.

Comment: Generally speaking, there are so many ways you can write numbers and dates and times, that you don't want to convert *from* strings *to* such values. Typically you make sure always to store and transmit such values in numeric form (integers, floats, or records of such), and only convert such a value to a textual representation when it is to be displayed in a GUI or written to a text file. If you need to store or transmit it as text, use a strictly defined format. Then you can write your own converter that interprets that particular format.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand you were first. please post your comment as an answer. I read the Delphi basics page about StrToFloat and did not go further to read the Delphi docs. Thank you.

Comment: @JerryDodge I will. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`StrToFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.StrToFloat):

> Thousand separators and currency symbols are not allowed in the string.

Generally speaking, there are so many different ways you can write numbers and dates and times, that you don't want to convert *from* strings (textual representations) *to* such values.

Typically you make sure always to store and transmit such values in numeric form (for instance, as integers, floats, or records of such values), and you only convert such a value to a textual representation when it is to be displayed in a GUI or written to a text file.

If you need to store or transmit it as text, use a strictly defined format. Then you can write your own converter that interprets that particular format without ambiguity.